# mule until-successful router: is objectStore mandatory?

Tags: mule

I am consuming a message from JMS queue and submitting it to a SOAP base web service. I want to make sure that I provide guaranteed delivery of the message to the web service where I am submitting the message.

I'm looking at two options 
1. Use until-successful router (preferred) and if unable to transmit the message put it in Dead Letter Queue.
2. Use JMS transactions, and if the transmission of message to the web service fails rollback the transaction and the JMS message stays in the queue.

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="ws.message"/>
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore"
              dlqEndpoint-ref="dlqChannel"
              maxRetries="3"
              secondsBetweenRetries="10">
...
</until-successful>
```

I am more inclined towards using until–successful router but the concern that I have is it requires a mandatory ObjectStore. I do not want to store the message in database/object store, instead push it to some JMS queue/a dead letter queue and consume it from there.

Any helpful tips or suggestions to handle the situation are appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use until-successful, a reference to an `objectStore` is mandatory. Mule uses this object to store messages between retries. Also, you should use a persistent object store to avoid message loss in case of the Mule server or your application crashes. 
Until-successful router should be the preferred method for this use case IMO. It will make the config easier to read and maintain vs using just jms queues.